# Why can't we explain two-mirrors thought experiment with traversial space contraction?

Tags: special-relativity

Suppose we have two-mirrors clocks and two inertial frames, one moving relatively to mirrors. As long as $c$ is constant in every inertial frame and light beam path is different in different inertial frames we conclude that $\Delta t \neq \Delta t'$. But how do we know that $L$, distance between mirrors, stays the same in different inertial frames? Can't we just say that $L'$ becomes shorter and this way time between bounces remains the same?

[[image: Classical explanation of two-mirrors experiment: <span class=]$\Delta t' \neq \Delta t $" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tFhX.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is a nice suggestion, but the problem is that you need a theory that accounts for the fact that the speed of light is the same in every direction, and your suggestion is not compatible with that objective.

More specifically, by supposing there is a transverse length contraction, you are eliminating any time difference between the two frames, so that dt'=dt. Imagine then that you and I stand together and flash a light which heads off to the left and right, and I stand still but you walk after the light to the right at 1m/s. After a second in my frame, the light is a distance c away in each direction, but in your frame it is c-1 meters away in one direction and c+1 meters away in the other. How would you explain that in a way that is consistent with your suggestion, given that it implies that you and I experience the same time?

Answer (score 0):

We could, that's just not the way that the system works.

One standard example involves a train passing through a tunnel and the tunnel and the train both put a paintbrush a meter above some shared ground plane, something that they can agree on, and then they both paint each other. To preserve the spirit of relativity you would want the paint brushes to either both be above or below the paint lines... But this seems very hard to arrange if we put both brushes on the same side of the train—surely either (a) they collide or (b) one objectively passes over the other.

That's not my favorite way to do the problem, my favorite way is to look at the infinitesimal Lorentz boosts and derive $\gamma$ from that. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/583255/73490) for some discussion. To first order the *only* physical effect of relativity is the relativity of simultaneity, and *length contraction and time dilation* are just the intertwining of the relativity of simultaneity and the Galilean transformation. What you have to described would be a new first order effect, one which couples different orthogonal directions and therefore probably does not play well with rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we follow your suggestion by letting the transverse length (perpendicular to the direction of motion) contract, the Michelson-Morley experiment shows that the longitudinal length (in the direction of motion) must be even shorter precisely by the factor

$$(1)\ \frac{L_{lo}}{L_{tr}}=\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}=1/\gamma$$

Of course, there are infinitely many ways to achieve this result: a) We could expand the transverse length by the factor $\gamma$ while letting the longitudinal length unchanged, or b) we could let the transverse length unchanged and contract the longitudinal length by the factor $1/\gamma$, or we could choose one of the infinitely many combination besides a) and b) satisfying relation (1).

A further examination of this question shows that the relativity principle as well as the constancy of light speed require that the transformations connecting inertial frames must be Lorentz transformation, according to which the transverse length must be completely unchanged, while the longitudinal length undergoes Lorentz contraction, thus solution b) is correct.

Fur further information see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment#Length_contraction_and_Lorentz_transformation

Answer (score 0):

Make each clock out of two mirrors attached by a vertical post.  Mount a piece of chalk on each of the mirrors.

Make the chalk long enough so that when the two clocks pass each other, the chalk on the shorter clock will leave marks on the post of the longer clock.

Those marks will tell you which clock is shorter.  That in turn will tell you which clock is moving. But the first postulate of relativity does not allow you to do any experiment whose conclusion is ``this is the clock that's moving''.  So the vertical contraction can't be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This idea is called the Voigt transform

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woldemar_Voigt

It is indeed a mathematically legitimate coordinate transform and it does preserve the invariance of c (the 2nd postulate), but it violates the principle of relativity (the 1st postulate). As a result the Voigt transform is compatible with the Michelson–Morley experiment and the Kennedy–Thorndike experiment, but it is ruled out by the Ives and Stillwell experiment (and others).